# Busca complexa com MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Tenho uma estrutura no mongoDB que possui quantidades de items diferentes dentro de um array chamado "items". Pra fazer a busca, estou usando o comando abaixo, que primeiro transforma o conteúdo em string, pois abaixo de this.items existe uma estrutura diferente, dependendo do objeto:

```
db.getCollection('docs').find('JSON.stringify(this.items[0].value).toLowerCase().indexOf("tex")!=-1')
```

Meu problema é que como não sei a quantidade de items em cada documento, teria que usar um wildcard tipo this.items[*].value, mas isso não funciona.

Alguém conhece alguma solução, ou tem outra ideia pra isso?

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido usando regex, postando a resposta aos interessados:

```
db.docs.find({items: {$elemMatch: {value: /tex/i}}});
```